# Script to configure Windows 7 New build

Tags: batch, windows-registry

I find myself installing Windows 7 on a regular basis and when I've installed the OS, I normally do the following:

1. Enable the 'Run' command in the start menu
2. Disable peek
3. Change power button action
4. Untick the 'Highlight newly installed programs'
5. Never combine taskbar buttons
6. Untick 'hide extensions for known file types'
7. Install firefox

These are some of the steps I take. It would be much easier if I could run a batch or registry file to do these steps for me.

My question is: How do I find out the registry keys for steps 1-6 ?

Thanks in advance. (And yes I realize I can't install firefox in the registry!)

Answer (score 2):

I believe these are the keys you need:

```
Enable RUN in Start:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
    NoRun   REG_DWORD    0x00000000

Disable Peek:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM
    EnableAeroPeek   REG_DWORD    0x00000000

Change Power Button Action:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
    Start_PowerButtonAction    REG_DWORD    0x*

Untick 'Highlight Newly Installed Programs':
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
    Start_NotifyNewApps   REG_DWORD    0

Never Combine Taskbar Buttons:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
    TaskbarGlomLevel    REG_DWORD   00000002

Untick 'Hide Extensions for Known File Types:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced
    HideFileExt   REG_DWORD    0x00000000
```

*Options for `Start_PowerButtonAction`:

1. Switch User: 0x00000100
2. Log Off: 0x00000001
3. Lock: 0x00000200
4. Restart: 0x00000004
5. Sleep: 0x00000010
6. Hibernate: 0x00000040
7. Shutdown: 0x00000002

Please note, these are obtained from various sources that seem reliable.  However, messing with your registry could do damage.  That being said, back up your data before trying these.  I am working on testing them myself, but it may take time.  I have wanted to do this for a while, so you inspired me to finally get around to it.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Firefox in a batch file is easy. Just download the full .exe installer and call it with a **`/S`** (for silent install). Here is the code I use. It may not work if you re-name the installer. YMMV.

> @echo off
>   cd /d %0..
>
> "Firefox Setup 24.0.exe" /S
>
> del "C:\Users\Public\Desktop\Mozilla*.lnk"